# What should we do when the OP's answer is deleted incorrectly for the reason 'does not provide an answer to the question'?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

See [Chart a line graph using linqpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75427940/chart-a-line-graph-using-linqpad)

A user asks a question and four hours later provides an answer (which is IMHO a perfectly valid answer).

His/her answer was then reviewed and deleted because it allegedly 'does not provide an answer to the question.'

The OP obviously believes that it does, and I tested the answer and it works fine.

What should be done?

In my view it is a valid question (and a valid answer) and so I don't want to recommend the question be close/deleted.

On the other hand, leaving the question as unanswered does not help anyone else.

Comment: Did you note, as well, what the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75429247/1) of the answer was? That, I suspect, is a large contributor to *why* it was deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here almost certainly stems from the original form of the answer, which was simply:

> posted the answer in the main question itself

There's multiple problems with that; the answer *isn't* an answer and the question *isn't* the place the post the answer.

The comment on the post (denoting it doesn't provide an answer) was placed *before* the post was edited, however, the moderator deletion did happen after the edit. As I don't know what the mod tools look like I don't know if the moderator would have seen that revision at the time they reviewed it.

As for what should be done, the post (as it stood when you posted), needed an edit, as the content was:

> jsonData.Chart(c=>c.entryTime,c=>c.cumulativegains, Util.SeriesType.Line).Dump(); will enable plotting it as line chart from json.

The code should be in a code fence. As a result you should edit the post, to make it presentable, and then raise a custom mod flag explaining the problem, and that you feel that the post is now a *good* answer and should be undeleted.

Zoe has now done all that, so the problem is resolved, but in the future, a Custom Moderator flag (for posts deleted by a moderator), is what is needed. If it's not mod deleted, as a user with >=20k reputation, you can simply cast an undelete vote.

Comment: ". If it's not mod deleted, as a user with >=10k reputation, you can simply cast an undelete vote" - there's a second case here; if it's deleted from review, the answer OP can single-handedly undelete the post

Comment: So the initial downvote was valid and the problem was maybe just the mod deleted it without realising the answer had been edited. I tried editing the answer and it did not allow me and didn't try the flag option as I incorrectly assumed it would not have worked either.

Comment: If looks that 10K rep only allows me to vote to undelete questions but not answers. I would need >= 20k reputation to be able to vote to undelete answers (assuming they hadn't been deleted by a moderator)

Comment: Corrected, @sgmoore .

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I could be wrong, but I thought that "normal" users couldn't vote to undelete a post that was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine You are indeed correct. To be clear, I replied to a case specifically about posts that weren't mod deleted. If it's deleted by non-mod users from a review queue, that's the only case the single-handed OP undeletion applies. If a mod deletes, even if it's from a queue, then only mods can undelete, as usual.